# CodeBlocks C++ Output Files

Tags: c++, file, output, codeblocks

I am programming for the Olympiad and I was working on some algorithm problems. A very stupid and strange bug came across. I can't work with output files for a reason. I tried opening an old project and everything was working fine, but whenever I create a new project it gets broken. I've never met this problem and I worked a lot of CodeBlocks, here is the code, though I don't think the problem is from my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;
const int N = 18;
int sol = 0, a[N], s, n;
bool numere[N];
void bkt (int v[])
{
    int i, nr, j;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if (numere[a[i]] == false)
        {
            nr = a[i];
            numere[a[i]] = true;
            v[0] = 1;
            for (j = 0; j + nr <= s; j++)
                if (v[j] != 0)
                    v[j] += 1;
            for (j = 1; j <= s; j++)
                sol += v[j];
            bkt (v);
            for (j = 0; j + nr <= s; j++)
                if (v[j] != 0)
                    v[j] -= 1;
            numere[a[i]] = false;
        }
    }
}
int main ()
{
    FILE *in, *out;
    in = fopen ("monezi.in", "r");
    out = fopen ("monezi.out", "w");
    fscanf (in, "%d%d", &n, &s);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        fscanf (in, "%d", &a[i]);
    int v[18];
    for (i = 0; i <= 18; i++)
        v[i] = 0;
    bkt (v);
    fprintf (out, "dds");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: mention error statement  or compiler messages.

Comment: None, this is the problem.

Comment: @DanC Well, you never call `fclose(out);`.

Comment: You should also check if your `fopen` work.

Comment: @DanC Accept the answer if it helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in this code is : you have decalred `int v[18];` Array of size 18 (0~17) and  your Loop  `for (i = 0; i <= 18; i++)` is causing Illegal memory access. it should be :

`for (i = 0; i < 18; i++)`